# Exclude Entities in Legend (Scatter and Line) - Matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter

I've tried many combinations to fix this from forums, etc., but each one doesn't solve my problem.  I have two `line` plots and two `scatter` plots.  I wish to only display the two `scatter` plots in the `legend`.

Here is my code:

```
line([-4, 4],[0,0], 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', [0 0 0]); % Do not want this in Legend
hold on
line([0, 0],[-4,4], 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', [0 0 0]); % Do not want this in Legend
hold on
i_h = scatter(valence_i, arousal_i,'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b');
legend(i_h, 'Induced Emotion')
hold on
p_h = scatter(valence_p, arousal_p, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r');
legend(p_h, 'Perceived Emotion')
axis([-4 4 -4 4])
xlabel('Valence')
ylabel('Arousal')
```

The code does indeed exclude the `line` objects, but the last call to `legend` overwrites the previous one.  The `line` objects are simply just marking out a cross in the middle of the plot, hence why they are not desired in the `legend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one call to legend:

```
legend ( [i_h p_h], 'Induced Emotion', 'Perceived Emotion' )
```